# Google Maps V3: Updating Markers Periodically

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've followed the PHP/MYSQL tutorial on Google Maps found **[here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html)**.

I'd like the markers to be updated from the database every 5 seconds or so.

It's my understanding I need to use Ajax to periodicity update the markers, but I'm struggling to understand where to add the function and where to use **setTimeout()** etc

All the other examples I've found don't really explain what's going on, some helpful guidance would be terrific!

This is my code (Same as Google example with some **var** changes):

```
function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.80815648152641, 140.95355987548828),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file

  downloadUrl("nwmxml.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML; 
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var host = markers[i].getAttribute("host");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("active");
      var lastupdate = markers[i].getAttribute("lastupdate");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + "Host: </b>" + host + "<br>" + "<b>Last Updated: </b>" + lastupdate + "<br>";
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);

    }

  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

I hope somebody can help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note I have not tested this as I do not have a db with xml handy

First of all you need to split your load() function into a function that initializes the map & loads the markers on domready and a function that you will use later to process the xml & update the map with. This needs to be done so you do not reinitialize the map on every load.

Secondly you need to decide what to do with markers that are already drawn on the map. For that purpose you need to add them to an array as you add them to the map. On second update you have a choice to either redraw the markers (rebuild the array) or simply update the existing array. My example shows the scenario where you simply clear the old markers from the screen (which is simpler).

```
//global array to store our markers
    var markersArray = [];
    var map;
    function load() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(37.80815648152641, 140.95355987548828),
            zoom : 13,
            mapTypeId : 'roadmap'
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // your first call to get & process inital data

        downloadUrl("nwmxml.php", processXML);
    }

    function processXML(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        //clear markers before you start drawing new ones
        resetMarkers(markersArray)
        for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var host = markers[i].getAttribute("host");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("active");
            var lastupdate = markers[i].getAttribute("lastupdate");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var html = "<b>" + "Host: </b>" + host + "<br>" + "<b>Last Updated: </b>" + lastupdate + "<br>";
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map : map,
                position : point,
                icon : icon.icon,
                shadow : icon.shadow
            });
            //store marker object in a new array
            markersArray.push(marker);
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);


        }
            // set timeout after you finished processing & displaying the first lot of markers. Rember that requests on the server can take some time to complete. SO you want to make another one
            // only when the first one is completed.
            setTimeout(function() {
                downloadUrl("nwmxml.php", processXML);
            }, 5000);
    }

//clear existing markers from the map
function resetMarkers(arr){
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i].setMap(null);
    }
    //reset the main marker array for the next call
    arr=[];
}
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Michal, well explained, the map is displayed but I cant get the nodes to appear, 

 **[Here](http://pastebin.com/TDgTcK6y)** is my page in full

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please post your sample xml (maybe 2 updates worth so I can debug it)

Comment: Sure **[XML Sample 1](http://pastebin.com/BxTuW4En)** , **[XML Sample 2](http://pastebin.com/h89hgW86)**

The location doesn't change often, but the value of active will :)

Comment: **Firebug returned:** 

`data is not defined - downloadUrl("nwmxml.php", processXML(data));`

It appears it cant get the XML data from the php script?

Comment: I edited the script - my bad the line downloadUrl("nwmxml.php", processXML(data)); should be downloadUrl("nwmxml.php", processXML); and map variable should be global in scope

Comment: Thanks, its working now, I also moved the `var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;` line so the `infoWindow` variable is in global scope, allowing the info window to appear. It closes on each refresh but I'm sure there is a way round this, thanks again for all your help!

Comment: thank you for the code.. is there a way to be able to keep the infowindow and content the same, just update the lat and lon for markers?

Comment: i have done the same thing as above, still my map markers are not visible on the map. link for mycode is :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34081564/google-maps-v3-updating-existing-markers-only-periodically-after-x-seconds-with

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function() { 
    downloadUrl("conection/cargar_tecnicos.php", function(data) {

        var xml = data.responseXML;
         markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
         removeAllMarkers();
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
              var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
            var fecha = markers[i].getAttribute("fecha");
            var id_android = markers[i].getAttribute("id_android");
            var celular = markers[i].getAttribute("celular");
            var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
            var logo = markers[i].getAttribute("logo");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

           var html = "<div class='infowindow'>"
                        +"<br/><div style='text-align:center;'><img src="+logo+"><br/>"    
                        +"<b>" + name + "</b></div><br/>"
                        +"<br/><label><b>Celular:</b></label>" + celular+""
                        +"<br/><label><b>Id Android:</b></label>" + id_android+""
                        +"<br/><label><b>Fecha y Hora:</b></label>" + fecha+""
                        +"<br/><br/><div style='text-align:center;'><a><input style=';' id='pop' type='image' value='"+id+"' class='ASD' img src='img/vermas.png' title='Detalles'/></a></div></div>";
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
             marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                position: point,
                icon: icon.icon,
                shadow: icon.shadow,
                title:name
            });

            openInfoWindow(marker[i], map, infoWindow, html);   
          marker[i].setMap(map);
        }
    });

},10000);
}
function removeAllMarkers(){// removes all markers from map
    for( var i = 0; i < marker.length; i++ ){
            marker[i].setMap(null);
}
}
```