# Google Maps V3: Updating Markers

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have some issues with Google maps api v3. I managed to create a map where new markers are displayed when the user drag the map. However, it do not delete the past markers. I have read many tutorials and thread (especially this one: [Google Maps V3: Updating Markers Periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626134/google-maps-v3-updating-markers-periodically)) without success.

Here is my main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Développez avec les API Google Maps</title>
<style type="text/css">
 html {
  height: 100%;
 }
 body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
 #map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
 }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function createXmlHttpRequest() {
    try {
        if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined') {
            return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        } else if (window["XMLHttpRequest"]) {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        changeStatus(e);
    }
    return null;
};

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var status = -1;
    var request = createXmlHttpRequest();
    if (!request) {
        return false;
    }

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            try {
                status = request.status;
            } catch (e) {
            }
            if (status == 200) {
                callback(request.responseText, request.status);
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {};
            }
        }
    }
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    try {
        request.send(null);
    } catch (e) {
        changeStatus(e);
    }
};

function xmlParse(str) {
  if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  }

  if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') { 
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }

  return createElement('div', null);
}

 var map;

 function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.7, 2.5);
  var myOptions = {
   zoom: 6,
   center: latlng,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

  downloadUrl("getPoi2.php", function(data) { 

   var xml = xmlParse(data);
   var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    createMarker(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")), markers[i].getAttribute('titre'));
   }
  });

        /* Ici, on ajoute l'écouteur d'événement suite à un glisser / déposer  */ 
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
        var bds = map.getBounds();
        var South_Lat = bds.getSouthWest().lat();
        var South_Lng = bds.getSouthWest().lng();
        var North_Lat = bds.getNorthEast().lat();
        var North_Lng = bds.getNorthEast().lng();
            downloadUrl("getPoi.php?maxlat="+North_Lat+"&minlat="+South_Lat+"&minlong="+South_Lng+"&maxlong="+North_Lng, function(data) { 
            var xml = xmlParse(data);
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                createMarker(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")), markers[i].getAttribute('titre'));
            }
            });
        });
 }

 function createMarker(lat, lng, titre){
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: latlng,
   map: map,
   title: titre
  });

 }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And there is my getPoin.php:

```
<?php
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$bdd = "citiesinvaders";
mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db($bdd) or die("erreur de connexion à la base
de données");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM location order by city desc limit 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$node = $dom->createElement("marker");
$newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
$newnode->setAttribute("city", $result["city"]);
$newnode->setAttribute("lat", $result["latitude"]);
$newnode->setAttribute("lng", $result["longitude"]);
}
$xmlfile = $dom->saveXML();
echo $xmlfile;
?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: To clarify... When the map is moved the markers are placed over the old markers? A.K.A. They are 'doubling up' on map drag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the google.maps.Marker objects created, delete them before creating new ones.

```
var map;
var gmarkers = [];


/* Ici, on ajoute l'écouteur d'événement suite à un glisser / déposer  */ 
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
  var bds = map.getBounds();
  var South_Lat = bds.getSouthWest().lat();
  var South_Lng = bds.getSouthWest().lng();
  var North_Lat = bds.getNorthEast().lat();
  var North_Lng = bds.getNorthEast().lng();
  downloadUrl("getPoi.php?maxlat="+North_Lat+"&minlat="+South_Lat+"&minlong="+South_Lng+"&maxlong="+North_Lng, function(data) { 
    var xml = xmlParse(data);
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

    // hide and delete the existing markers
    for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
      gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    gmarkers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      createMarker(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")), markers[i].getAttribute('titre'));
    }
  });
});

function createMarker(lat, lng, titre){
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    title: titre
  });
  // keep a reference to created markers so you can remove them 
  gmarkers.push(marker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on my understanding of your question... To clarify... When the map is moved the markers are placed over the old markers? A.K.A. They are 'doubling up' on map drag?

Create an array to hold the markers.

```
var markers = [];
```

Then, add the markers to the array in 'createMarker()' function. Also, check to see if a marker has already been created, and if so, do not recreate.

```
function createMarker(lat, lng, titre) {
  for( marker in markers ) {
      var coord = marker.getgetPosition();
      if( coord.lat() == lat && coord.lng() == lng )
          return;
  }
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  markers.push( new google.maps.Marker({
     position: latlng,
     map: map,
     title: titre
  }));
}
```

Comment: In fact, you answered part of it. But my aim would be to delete every single marker that have been created before. Even the ones that are not anymore displayed on the screen. I was trying something like what you said but don't really succeed.