# Update Google Map Center Dynamically With Changing Markers

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a Google Map where its markers are loaded from a MySQL database and update them on the map using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps and [Google Maps V3: Updating Markers Periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626134/google-maps-v3-updating-markers-periodically). However I need to update the map center with the changing markers. Map center should be the marker location. How can I do this? Where should I put the following line with the changing latitude and longitude?

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
```